# How to Toggle a div's visibility by using a button click

Tags: javascript, css, html, show-hide

Below is my javascript code which i used to show a `div` when clicked on a `button`.

How can I hide it when clicked again? And then on clicking it, `div` should be visible again?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _hidediv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
    if(_hidediv)
        _hidediv();
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    _hidediv = function () { div.style.display = 'none'; };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Give me one moment, I'll get you a demo.

Comment: Using jquery you can use toggle , very simple

Comment: thanks jack for considering this question, take your time and please give me an answer... thanks once again.

Comment: Do you have a button for each div ?

Comment: yes Sheikh Heera i am having a button for my div, in fact one button for each div, which will toggle between show and hide of its div.

Comment: yes, i can use toggle using jquery but i am not allowed to use jquery, Mr. FaceOfJock

Comment: @user2827600, Your `HTML` will help to understand the way you want it, otherwise I can think of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/933Ht/).

Comment: Correct answer is below.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In case you are interested in a jQuery soluton:

This is the HTML

```
<a id="button" href="#">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="item">Item</div>
```

This is the jQuery script

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $( "#item" ).toggle();
});
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/

If you don't know how to use jQuery, you have to use this line to load the library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

And then use this line to start:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // code to fire once the library finishes downloading.
});
</script>
```

So for this case the final code would be this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#item" ).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if you need anything else

You can read more about jQuery here: http://jquery.com/

Comment: OP did not tagged jQuery... so why jQuery then ?

Comment: True, but OP also mentioned he is new at javascript programming, so perhaps he doesn't even know about jQuery and that is why I expanded my answer with jQuery installation as well.

Comment: `OP` mentioned in his comment `yes, i can use toggle using jquery but i am not allowed to use jquery, Mr. FaceOfJock`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I started writing this answer before the OP said that. Sorry about that. Anyway, this answer might work for someone else then.

Comment: just because JQuery wasn't tagged doesn't mean it isn't useful. JQuery *should* be used in this case, it is much easier and makes more sense. This is a great answer and the OP should consider using JQ

Comment: @Jan, I don't have any problem with your answer, it was just a reminder.

Comment: @MarkHall, really ? I thought it's a short form `Opposite` till now but learned today, thanks.

Comment: yes sir you are right, i will use jquery now and will also learn about it more, but sir, will this script be able to close div when clicked anywhere on the page, and also when i want to open another div by clicking on another button, will this automatically close

Comment: @SheikhHeera http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms

Comment: By default it shows the item content. How can I hide the item content by default.

Comment: Perfect. Can you plz tell me if I use your this toggle, how I can make the div invisible in the page load and than togle it if the button is clicked ?

Comment: @Nikonah just make the item have a display of none on the CSS.

Answer (score 71):

To switch the display-style between `block` and `none` you can do something like this:

```
function toggleDiv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/2/

Comment: what if display style not added to DIV initially??

Comment: then div.style.display == "none" will be false and the style will be set to "none"

Comment: for followers, this means "it still works if no div.style.display initially"

Comment: works for _inline-block_ too

`div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "inline-block" : "none";`

Comment: Note: this will not work on the first click if the div is already hidden when the user loads the page. To combat this, change `div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";` to `div.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";`

Comment: what if you want this to be dynamic? I have a function that takes in an id, and toggles the display. This will not work if i use other displays, for example, block, inline-block, flex etc

Answer (score 4):

jQuery would be the easiest way if you want to use it, but this should work.

```
function showHide(){
    var e = document.getElementById('e');

    if ( e.style.display !== 'none' ) {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: what if display style not added to DIV initially??

Comment: The display should automatically be block, especially if you use a css reset, which I would highly recommend.

Comment: nope buddy, i have tried your code but it is not working as expected

Comment: You are correct, I'm sure I was using this code somewhere though. Give me a min unless you already have your answer.

Comment: Ok, well a pure js, no jQuery working solution is now in my answer. Link: http://lucienconsulting.com/dev/

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with jquery toggle. By this toggle or slideToggle you will get nice animation and effect also.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#details_content").css("display","none");
  $(".myButton").click(function(){
    $("#details_content").slideToggle(1000);
  })  
})
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h2 class="myButton" style="cursor:pointer">Click Me</h2>
    <div id="details_content">
        <h1> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h1> 
        <p>    of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHideDiv(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == null || e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: actually i was not clear from question... but from comments now.

Comment: Your most recent edit caused your script to break, FYI. If it is `null` it will already be block, and thus break your code.

Answer (score 0):

with JQuery `.toggle()`
you can accomplish it easily

```
$( ".target" ).toggle();
```

Comment: i cant see jQuery tag... do you?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 provides the [Collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/) for that. It's using JavaScript behind the scenes, but you don't have to write any JavaScript yourself.

This feature works for `<button>` and `<a>`.

If you use a `<button>`, you must set the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes:

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
  Toggle
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

If you use a `<a>`, you must use set `href` and `data-toggle`:

```html
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">
  Toggle
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```