# Hide a div onclick through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have done for showing a div on click i want to remove on another click. I want the div to be removed on another click.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
    <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Javascript

```
 function showDiv() {
       document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: Toggle a class.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Toggle a div's visibility by using a button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074171/how-to-toggle-a-divs-visibility-by-using-a-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the visibility of the div and do a toggle based on that.

```
 function showDiv() {
    if( document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display == "none") {
       document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
       document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the inline styling and use a class to toggle the display type. This is cleaner and you can easily reuse it for other elements.

```js
function showDiv(element) {
  document.querySelector(element).classList.toggle("invisible");
}
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcomeDiv" class="answer_list invisible"> WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv('#welcomeDiv')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showDiv() {
  var element = document.getElementById('welcomeDiv');
    if(!element.classList.contains('show')){
    element.classList.add('show');
    } else {
    element.classList.remove('show');
    }
       
       
 }
```

```css
.show {
   display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
    <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the current visibility of the DIV and let the javascript function do accordingly.

```
function showDiv() {
    if( document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display == "none") {
       //If it is not visible, make it visible
       document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
       //Else, make it invisible.
       document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "none"
    }
}
```